# Calling Built-In functions on DOM Elements Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is the second time Ive encountered this & this time decided to raise a question instead of finding an alternative solution.

Scenario:
We have a list of elements that we get from `document.getElementsByClassName`. The returned list is an array. Why can I NOT use the built-in array functions like `map, find, filter` on this returned array?

https://jsfiddle.net/xbka5pt2/

```
<div class="classy"></div>
<div class="classy"></div>
<div class="classy"></div>
<div class="classy"></div>
<div class="classy"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
let list = document.getElementsByClassName( "classy" );
console.log( list );
// the following returns a 'typeError':
// "list.map is not a function"
list.map( function( ele ){
    console.log( "ele is", ele );
});
```

I get the error: `TypeError: list.map is not a function` when I try & use the map function on the list array. Thanks.

Comment: Because it is not an array, it is a live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

Comment: Thanks David, how do I convert it to an array?

Comment: Since you are using ES6 you can simple call `Array.from(list)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because getElementsByClassname returns a HtmlCollection. Here is a working solution:

```
let list = document.getElementsByClassName("classy");
console.log(list);

Array.prototype.map.call(list, function(ele) {
  console.log("ele is", ele);
});
```

By calling the prototype from Array with the list as parameter you can map each function. Another possibility would be to call it with the *[]* Operator like this:

```
[].map.call(list, function (el) {...});
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.